# Kibana pie chart for text data

Tags: kibana

I have text data in Elastic, field name is `buildResult` , type is `text` and value can be either `Success` or `Failure`:

[image]
[image]

I want to have Pie chart to illustrate `Success` vs `Failure`

Could you please advice on chart setup or share some example for `text` type?

Comment: You can start from here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/_pie_chart.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the piechart using text filters to get the result you want.

The picture below is taken from the data configuration of the piechart visualization in Kibana.

This works for `string` fields - I guess it would work for `text` fields also.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what needed

Answer (score 1):

From what i know the best way is to use keyword data type in these cases

[elasticsearch keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html)

when the field is keyword you can use simple terms aggregation to split the pie between the deferent keywords

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but to use data type change was required

Comment: I think you can do it on `text` field as well